# Reanimated measure return type is any

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-reanimated

According to reanimated docs, the return type of the measure function should be

```
MeasuredDimensions
```

for some reason, I get a type any. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
  const aref = useAnimatedRef<View>();

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const measured = measure(aref);
    return {
      width: withTiming(pointerWidth.value),
      height: withTiming(pointerHeight.value),
    };
  });

  const gesture = useMemo(
    () =>
      Gesture.Tap()
        .onStart(() => {
          const measured = measure(aref);

          if (!measured) return;

          console.log({ measured });
        })
        .onEnd(() => {
          if (onPress) runOnJS(onPress)();
          console.log('on tap end');
        }),
    [onPress, aref],
  );
  return (
    <GestureDetector {...{ gesture }}>
      <View style={styles.button} {...{ pointerEvents }} ref={aref}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.ripple, animatedStyle]} />
        <Text style={styles.text}>{children}</Text>
      </View>
    </GestureDetector>
  );
```

Thanks for any help